# I want to use two observable collections on a same datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, code-behind

I was working with reports of a project. I was creating a profit report. Here I have to list both sales details and then sales return details. They come from different classes and so they are two different observable collections.
I want to list Sales details first, after completing sales then list sales return. I want this to be done on a single data grid

I have tried it using a data grid name and item source, but only sales return is listing

```
AllSalesProfitList = new ObservableCollection<SalesInvoice>(SalesInvoice.GetAllSalesProfitList(SelectQuerySales));

if (AllSalesProfitList.Count > 0)
{
    ReportContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    ListSalesReportView.ItemsSource = AllSalesProfitList;

    LabelTotalSalesAmountValue.Content = AllSalesProfitList.Sum(p => p.TotalSalesAmount);
}
else
{
    NoRecordCheck();
}

AllSalesReturnProfitList = new ObservableCollection<SalesReturnInvoice>(SalesReturnInvoice.GetAllSalesReturnProfitList(SelectQuerySalesReturn));

if (AllSalesReturnProfitList.Count > 0)
{
    ReportContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    ListSalesReportView.ItemsSource = AllSalesReturnProfitList;

    LabelTotalSalesReturnAmountValue.Content = AllSalesReturnProfitList.Sum(p => p.TotalSalesReturnAmount);
}
else
{
    NoRecordCheck();
}
```

### Expected Result

It should list all sales first, then sales return.

### Actual Result

Lists only sales return.

Comment: You should do joined collections then will set joined collection as ListSalesReportView.ItemsSource

Answer (score 0):

[CompositeCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.compositecollection?view=netframework-4.7.2) is the class that will do the trick. Indeed it

> Enables multiple collections and items to be displayed as a single
>   list.

So your code will be (more or less)

```
CompositeCollection compositeCollection = new CompositeCollection();
CollectionContainer cc1 = new CollectionContainer();
cc1.Collection = AllSalesProfitList;
CollectionContainer cc2 = new CollectionContainer();
cc2.Collection = AllSalesReturnProfitList;

compositeCollection.Add(cc1);
compositeCollection.Add(cc2);

ListSalesReportView.ItemsSource = compositeCollection;
```

I hope it can help you.